# Get the previous word of corresponding matching word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am facing issue to following sql query in javascript.

**let query ='SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID  = 1 And CustomerName=&name And CustomerAdd  = &&address And Salary =^salary;'**

Actually I have to find out all dynamic variable which have prefix as special character like &, &&, ^ sign.

Once dynamic variable find then needs to find corresponding column name. 
Example: for &name column name is Custoername,
for &&address column is CustomerAdd.

I am able to find special character word using regex of match. But how to find their corresponding column name in javascript. I don't have idea.

Please suggest something or let me know if more explanation is required.

Comment: Writing out a SQL query in JavaScript is a **bad** idea. I'm not exactly sure the case surrounding this, but you're exposing this to the client. Assuming you send this query off to the server, what's to stop me from finding that piece of JavaScript and sending a `DROP DATABASE`?

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes, I know but we have one requirement. If you have any idea how to get previous word then let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really understand what you're asking at all. I get that you want to replace these prefixed values but I don't understand the rules - what do the prefixes mean? You want your query to say `...And CustomerAdd = CustomerAdd`?

Comment: better put some rules(like compilation), to verify the query is exactly as intended and does not contain junk before you process further, this ensures whatever split rules you write will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

We can apply a regex over your SQL query string to find all placeholders with their corresponding column names.

```js
var regex = /(\S+)\s*=\s*(&&|&|\^)\s*(\S+)/g;
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 1 And CustomerName=&name And CustomerAdd = &&address And Salary =^salary;';
var m;

do {
  m = regex.exec(sql);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1] + ' ' + m[2] + ' ' + m[3]);
  }
} while (m);
```

### Demo

Comment: Why not an inline-snippet instead of an external demo?

Comment: @Tim...You are genius...In a short of time... you understand the problem and create the solution. thanks thanks and many thanks

Comment: @Tim.. If I want to get operator as well like '&name', '&&address' , '^salary' than what will be regex? I am talking about second output.. I want that come with operator.

Comment: @TylerRoper I am on a cell phone at the moment, and the demo wizard is not always available.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Understood! If you'd like it to be an inline snippet and aren't able to do it at the moment, I can edit it for you. Otherwise have a good one :)

Comment: @TylerRoper Feel free to edit, thanks.  Are you sure your last name isn't Durden?